# VBA sheet selection by Sheetname

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to reference a Sheet by sheet (name) so that if the client changes the Name it doesn't matter

I have a working solution but using the sheet name

this code works

```
Workbooks(wbImport).Activate ' 
Sheets("Invoiced").Select
Range(RangeStart).select
```

this doesn't

```
Workbooks(wbImport).Activate
Sheet17.Select
Range(RangeStart).select
```

This does

```
ThisWorkbook.activate
Sheet17.select
Range(RangeStart).select
```

("Invoiced" is the name of Sheet17)

but I use it throughout the code else where and it works fine.

Object not defined

Comment: Make sure `Sheet17` is the name of sheet in VBA not the name in the excel file.

Comment: Please add more context, What is Sheet17 for example? What is ThisWorkbook?
If you provide more context, and code, people will be more effective trying to help you

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: I use a Form to gather from the user the name of a spreadsheet - this is 'wbImport'.  Data is manipulated and formatted in the spreadsheet where the code is held - 'ThisWorkbook' is a standard VBA function and is the sheet where the code is hold.  'Invoiced' is Sheet17 in the list of Excel objects and is the sheet that I wish to write the data too.  If I refer to this sheet by its Name ('Invoiced') then the select function works and I can write the data in the appropriate area.  If I try to use the codename (17) then it doesn't work.  In all other areas Sheet?.select works fine.